# Alternative Formula for Josephus Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was having some students in my high school class try to write the solution to the Josephus Problem (when k=2) and one of my freshman came up with the following:

$f(n) = f(n - 1)+2, f(2^a) = 1$ where $a = 0, 1, 2, ...$

Is this a valid way to write the solution to the Josephus problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to be slightly more careful.

For $a=0,1,2, \ldots,$
$$f(n) = \begin{cases}f(n-1)+2 &, n = 2^a+l,  0<l<2^a
\\1 &, n=2^a\end{cases}$$

That is one has to specify when does the formula $f(n)=f(n-1)+2$ holds.